# How to get D6 as basic item for Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I've seen in many streams that Isaac has D6 from the very beginning. How can I get it?  P. S. I have all characters except Magda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noted in the [Rebirth Wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/The_D6), which is actually correct in this case, the D6 is unlocked by beating the Cathedral as Blue Baby/??? (who in turn in unlocked by beating Mom's Heart 10 times).

Once it has been unlocked, Isaac will carry it as a starting item.